# How to run a WAM project in LAMP

Tags: migration, lamp, wamp

I done my project in WAMP. Is it possible to run in LAMP also? I used the XML DOM for data storing instead of MYSQL. If it is possible what we have to do for run in LAMP.

Answer (score 0):

The technologies you have used (the Apache MySQL, PHP) are cross platform by their nature. As long as you have not used them in non-crossplatform ways you should be fine.